# Add items to sharepoint list from parse json if missing

Tags: json, sharepoint, power-automate

I have two lists, one is 8 items that are in a parse JSON, the other is a Sharepoint list with 3 items (Get items from Classes List), these lists have a unique ID in common. In Flow, I need help adding new items from the parse JSON array into the Sharepoint list, but only if they are missing from the list by that "ID".

I know I need to do an Apply Each and a Create Item, but this will only add the 8 items from Parse JSON into the list without checking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to only append items those IDs are not in the SP list. I think you can add a check before the 'Create' action.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-items

With above action, you can check if the item with the parsed id exists or not using a filter query.